# My laptop is under load when I'm not using it

Tags: laptop

I went away for a while and the temperature of the laptop rose to 60 degrees, maybe it's the antivirus that warms it in the background? But now when I'm sitting it's only 45 degrees. What could it be?

Comment: If Windows Defender hasn't done a scan in some time then it may be trying to do a background scan when it detects the system is idle. If it last longer than a few hours is when there might be a concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is a maintenance task running in the background. On a Windows PC, that includes

- Windows Update - not only the initial update, but subsequent cleanup
- [Search Indexer](https://windows101tricks.com/windows-10-search-indexer-high-cpu-usage/) (indexing changed files)
- [Windows Defender](https://www.top-password.com/blog/limit-windows-defender-cpu-usage-in-windows-10/) malware scan

However, those three tasks tend to use more disk I/O than CPU power, and it seems odd that the temp should rise to 60°C.

A less likely possibility is that malware is running on the PC, e.g. a [crypto-miner](https://freemanlaw.com/mining-explained-a-detailed-guide-on-how-cryptocurrency-mining-works/). Perform an [offline malware scan](https://www.techsupportall.com/best-offline-free-virus-removal-tools-scanners-portable/) if the issue recurs.

To check what is using so much CPU time,

- Leave Task Manager open to Details tab, ordered by CPU use,
- disable display blanking and screen saver (e.g., with [Don't Sleep](https://www.softwareok.com/?Download=DontSleep))
- and let the PC run for a while to let that background process resume.